# Django mail sending error:[ Error 10061]

Tags: django, email

I followed The Django Book to Chapter 7. When I was trying the example of contact, I met this mail sending error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is the error information:

error at /contact/
[Errno 10061] 
Request Method: POST

```
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact/<br>
```

Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: error
Exception Value:[Errno 10061] 
Exception Location: C:\Python27\lib\socket.py in create_connection, line 571
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
Python Version: 2.7.2
Python Path: 
['D:\Workspace\DJhello',
 'D:\Workspace\DJhello',
 'D:\Workspace\DJhello\src',
 'C:\Python27\DLLs',
 'C:\Python27\lib',
 'C:\Python27\lib\plat-win',
 'C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk',
 'C:\Python27',
 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages',
 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32',
 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib',
 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin',
 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
 'C:\Windows\system32\python27.zip']
Server time:    Thu, 14 Mar 2013 12:08:14 +0800`enter code here`

Here is my code:

```
def contact(request):
    errors = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('subject', ''):
            errors.append('Enter a subject.')
        if not request.POST.get('message', ''):
            errors.append('Enter a message.')
        if request.POST.get('email') and '@' not in request.POST['email']:
            errors.append('Enter a valid e-mail address.')
        if not errors:
            send_mail(
                request.POST['subject'],
                request.POST['message'],
                request.POST.get('email', 'noreply@example.com'),
                ['siteowner@example.com'],
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
    return render_to_response('contact_form.html',
        {'errors': errors, 
        'subject': request.POST.get('subject', ''),
        'message': request.POST.get('message', ''), 
        'email': request.POST.get('email', '')}, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Is your mail server running and waiting for connection on specified IP and port?

Comment: Do you have email config in your settings?

Answer (score 0):

Check your email settings are correct:

settings.py:

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "youremail@gmail.com"

EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"

EMAIL_HOST_USER = "youremail@gmail.com"

EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = "yourpasswordforyouremailaccount"

EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

**These are the settings for gmail as far as I am aware.**

Answer (score -1):

Before you send mail, you must set some variables in your `settings.py` :

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.163.com' # replace with your smtp server's address
EMAIL_POST = 25 # replace with your smtp server's port
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'username' # replace with your smtp server account username
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'abc' # replace with your smtp server account password
```

**Note: you should have a smtp server or a smtp server accout.**

**How to get a free smtp server account?** [This site offers free smtp services.](http://www.serversmtp.com)

Maybe you want to dig into django docs, [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_HOST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-EMAIL_HOST)